# Using CoreData on iOS to handle something that is akin multiple Documents

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite, core-data

I've been trying to determine an elegant way to deal with implementing a design using CoreData on iOS that is akin to handling multiple Documents.

As a background I have a Training App in which I'd like to support in-App puchase of Training Courses. These will be probably be a bundle of files containing a `.sqlite` and some supporting media files which will end up in `CourseName` subfolders in the App Library folder when they are downloaded.

I'd like to be able to do support listing all the `Coursenames` in a Table at the Root level of my App and switch between them based on which one a user selects.

My gut feeling is that I could switch the Store to the appropriate sqlite.

```
    NSString *sqliteFileForCourseName = [self sqliteFileForCourseName];
    storeURL = [[self applicationLibraryDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:sqliteFileForCourseName];
    if(!__persistentStoreCoordinator)
        __persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    if (![__persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:options error:&error])
    // handle error
```

I think it would then be a matter of managing the items in `[persistentStoreCoordinator persistentStores]`.

I'm not sure if this is the right level (mulitple Persistent Stores) to handle the feature or if it could be done at the NSManagedObjectContext level.

I could live with the Courses being readonly when they are loaded from the Library folder if it simplifies things to have one writable Store and multiple read only stores (perhaps `NSInMemoryStoreType`?)

Answer (score 0):

If all you are doing is handling a list of documents then `NSArray` and `NSUserDefaults` is probably your best bet. It's less technically impressive but the simplest solution is usually the easiest.

As for each Document, I wouldn't bother with a sqlite database unless you really have lots of data to read. I would go for an archive with a .json file that provides information for that Document i.e.

index.json

```
{
    "name":"Document 1",
    "author":"Bob Smith"
    "pages":[
        { "title":"Title", "path":"title.html" },
        { "title":"Contents", "path":"contents.html" },
        { "title":"1", "path":"contents/1.html" }
    ]
}
```

where each page is a html file (or whatever format you want) and it's location is specified in the json description of the document.

Just make a Document object that implements NSCoding - create that from the above JSON and store it in your NSUserDefaults.

Then, on startup, just populate your UITableView from the array you read in from NSUserDefaults using the title as the text in your UITableViewCell.

---

However, there might be a valid reason for sqlite - is there anything particularly complicated that you are planning to do with the documents?

Comment: Thanks for the Reply. My App is already working with CoreData writing and reading sqlite. So generating these Bundles containing sqlite and the supporting media files is very straightforward. I'm trying to find the path of least resistance (or least coding) to switch between the sqlite files in these Bundles.

Comment: Ah, my answer isn't much help then! Sorry! I wouldn't try to load all the stores at the same time, I don't know how that would work :( I would just create a new persistent store each time the user selected a document. However, there's no reason why the method you suggest in your question won't work :)

Answer (score 0):

Managing these as persistent stores seems exactly right. That's what they're designed for. You can't really control this at the MOC level. A single logical "document" can have many MOCs. It is required in most cases to have a separate MOC per thread for instance. The correct place to separate these things is at the persistent store.